# How to get access to system .so libraries un android

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I want to write fm radio for my phone. I decompiled it,and noticed,what it use libfmjni.so,which i found in system folder. But when i try to use it,i get exception:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libfmjni.so" needed or dlopened by "/system/lib/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"

I tryed to load it in jni\armeAbe folder,but i have the same effect. My phone is rooted. Also i not understand,why in decompiled app (i did the same),it load fmjni instead of libfmjni. Thanks everybody for any help.

Comment: The error message could not be clearer, I think. The Android runtime is configured not to allow you to load libraries from the system directory.

Comment: @Botje But i tryed to load it to jni dir too.

Comment: _"it load fmjni instead of libfmjni."_ When you use `System.loadLibrary` you must leave out the prefix and file extension (i.e.  `fmjni` instead of `libfmjni.so`).

Answer (score 0):

add the following into you app/build.gradle,
that's working for me.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).